# Reinstalling Windows on an HP laptop

Tags: windows-8, installation

I bought a HP Envy m6 laptop with Windows 8 installed on it. I have a folder in the hard drive named 'recovery'. Now I have 2 questions:

- How can I tell whether this Windows installation is genuine?
- If I format the whole drive, then how can I reinstall Windows?

Comment: Create a (set of) recovery disk(s).  [HP PCs - Creating a Recovery Image on Discs or Saving a Recovery Image to a USB Flash Drive (Windows 8)](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03481733)

Comment: Recovery disks contain proprietary image of your OEM windows installation that shall enable you to restore the laptop back to factory original state. Do create recovery Disks for your own backup even though recovery partition exists. If you ever format entire disk including recovery partition and you did not create recovery disks or usb image then you will have to contact laptop manufacturer. It  might offer the same for a small price or take the laptop to its service centre whereby it could be restored back to original.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether your Windows is genuine by going to System Properties: **<kbd>Start</kbd> > Search 'System' (without quotation marks)**. The first link should be "System" or "System Properties".

In the left side of the window, it should have:

*Name of OS (in your case " Windows 8)
It should then have information about whether you have any service packs.*

If you scroll further down or go to bottom of page, it will have information on whether your PC is **activated and genuine.**

---

If you format you hard drive, Windows will be removed from the hard drive. If you want to reinstall it, you need to make sure you have **Windows installer on a flash drive or DVD**. You will then be able to boot from that flash drive and install Windows again.

**For a full guide use this link:**

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to reinstall Windows like it was when new.

1. [Create a set of HP Recovery discs](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c03481733) before you format it.
2. If you cannot create these discs [order them from HP](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/bph07143#AbT2)

Comment: How can I use those disks later ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of checking if your system is genuine  :

```
Run command prompt as Administrator and run the following commands:
slmgr -xpr  
slmgr -dli  
slmgr -dlv
```

Another way is to run MSDiag report.

The recovery partition contains original software along with proper system drivers for your machine with license key embedded, never try to format HDD by yourself.

There are various ways for formatting system via recovery image, the first two ways like others said is by making and using recovery discs or ordering one from HP.

Method 3 (Recommended only when you cannot open your system):

```
i. Restart computer  
ii. Keep tapping Esc button until you see a black screen 
with various options like diagnosis, bios, etc.
iii. Check the key for System recovery (F11 by default).
iv. Click on Troubleshot and then Recovery Manager.
vi. Choose Target OS.
vii.Open Minimized Image Recovery
```

Method 4:

```
i. If you have OEM version of windows instaled then it comes with a
 software called "HP Recovery Manager". Open It.
ii. Click on "HP recovery Environment" and then press yes.
iii. Click on minimized system recovery.
```

But every one recommend having Recovery Discs or Recovery drive (32GB USB at least, 3.0 HDD doesn't works).

Also, I made a **macrium reflect** image for my system, so, If I every lose my recovery discs and/or HDD I can get everything back.